# Differentiate between two ImageViews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimageview

I have two imageViews imageView1 and imageView2. I have given gestureRecognizer to move these both images. Now the problem is when i move first imageView near second imageView only second image view is displayed. But when i put first imageView on another image the first imageView should be displayed on the second imageView which is not happening.Can any body please tell me how can the first imageView gets view on the top of another imageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use something similar like this to drag your UIImageViews?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    test1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    test1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    test1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    test1.clipToBounds = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:test1];

    test2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 400, 100, 100)];
    test2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    test2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    test2.clipToBounds = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:test2];
}


CGPoint startLocation;
float diffX;
float diffY;

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if( [touch view] == test1)
    {
        startLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:test1];
    }

    if( [touch view] == test2)
    {
        startLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:test2];
    }
}


- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if( [touch view] == test1)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        diffX = location.x - startLocation.x;
        diffY = location.y - startLocation.y;
        test1.frame = CGRectMake(test1.frame.origin.x + diffX, test1.frame.origin.y + diffY, test1.frame.size.width, test1.frame.size.height);
        startLocation = test1.frame.origin;
    }

    if( [touch view] == test2)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        diffX = location.x - startLocation.x;
        diffY = location.y - startLocation.y;
        test2.frame = CGRectMake(test2.frame.origin.x + diffX, test2.frame.origin.y + diffY, test2.frame.size.width, test2.frame.size.height);
        startLocation = test2.frame.origin;
    }

}
```

//---*EDIT*---//
Added: cliptobounds in viewdidload

Comment: It is working absolutely fine but it is not clipping when it comes near the second imageView.

Comment: did you set the clipToBounds (BOOL) property?

Comment: Yes i have set it to yes in the touches moved method.But still i am having the same problem.

Comment: do it in the viewdidload and post me results

Comment: I have set this property to both the imageViews in viewDidLoad,But i am having the same problem.

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what you are trying to accomplish as precise as you can?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `UIView` method `bringSubviewToFront:`, and pass in the `UIImageView` that you want displayed on top.